# Convert js date to php timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Hi i am using js datetime and i sent this variable to php. Now i want to convert this js date to php datetime, but its not working. Here is what i want.

input :

> Mon Jul 31 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

Outut:

> 2017-07-31 06:00:00

Here is my code:

```
$dispatchDate = "Mon Jul 31 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)";
$dispatchDate = substr($dispatchDate, 0, strpos($dispatchDate, '('));
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($dispatchDate));
```

But its not working.

Comment: this looks like php code not javascript, but your tags refer to javascript

Comment: @marzelin, js variable is passed to php via a ajax call. now i want to convert this string to a php format. now got it?

Comment: but you want to do it on the server using php, right?

Comment: Just pass the JS timestamp (ie, milliseconds since Unix epoch) to PHP. You can then use `$dispatchDate = new DateTime('@' . ($timestampFromJs / 1000))` in PHP

Comment: You should be able to just use gmdate instead of date.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting time in GMT convert your time in PST

```
  <?php
    $dispatchDate = "Mon Jul 31 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)";
    $dispatchDate = substr($dispatchDate, 0, strpos($dispatchDate, '('));
    echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($dispatchDate." +5 hours"));       
  ?>
```

live demo : https://eval.in/836779

Comment: You have hard coded time zone +5 please provide better solution

Answer (score -1):

working solution and I think easiest : convert your javascript datetime into a int (timestamp) send the timestamp to your PHP and convert back your timestamp to a PHP datetime.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', your timestamp)
```